# RxJava chain requests and update UI

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I want to chain up three network calls with `RxJava`and `Retrofit`. The first call (retrieves the session token) has to be the first, the other two depend on this call and if the first call isn't finished before, the other two calls will result in an error.

For the other two calls, they should retrieve some information and update the UI. What would be the best way to proceed? 
I first thought about using the `zip Operator`, but I'm not sure if it respects the order of the requests and as it returns a value, it felt like abusing it to just use it to bundle up the requests without any further processing.

My second approach would be to flatmap the requests and use doOnNext to update the UI once, but I'm not certain if this is the correct way.

```
private void setUpInitialUIState() {
        restClient.requestSessionToken()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
                .flatMap(new Func1<SessionTokenResponse, Observable<CurrentPlmnResponse>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<CurrentPlmnResponse> call(SessionTokenResponse sessionTokenResponse) {
                        return restClient.requestCurrentPlmn();
                    }
                })
                .doOnNext(new Action1<CurrentPlmnResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(CurrentPlmnResponse currentPlmnResponse) {
                        if (!currentPlmnResponse.isError()) {
                            tvProvider.setText(currentPlmnResponse.getData().getFullName());
                        }
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Func1<CurrentPlmnResponse, Observable<MonitoringStatusResponse>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<MonitoringStatusResponse> call(CurrentPlmnResponse currentPlmnResponse) {
                        return restClient.requestMonitoringStatus();
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<MonitoringStatusResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                     Log.d("onError", throwable.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(MonitoringStatusResponse monitoringStatusResponse) {
                        if (monitoringStatusResponse != null && !monitoringStatusResponse.isError() && monitoringStatusResponse.getData().getSignalIcon() >= 0 && monitoringStatusResponse.getData().getSignalIcon() <= 5) {
                            ivSignalStrength.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("ic_signal_" + monitoringStatusResponse.getData().getSignalIcon(), "drawable", getPackageName()));
                            tvNetworkType.setText(getNetworkTypeTitle(monitoringStatusResponse.getData().getCurrentNetworkType()));
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends if you want your 2nd and 3rd calls to be executed in parallel or one after another. If in parallel go for the `.zip` and don't feel bad about it :)

3 tips on your (current) code (maybe you are aware already or slightly different in your app, so apologies):

- Catch the subscription returned from the `.subscribe` and kill (unsubscribe) at onDestroy the latest. If the app closes the network calls will continue to live.
- If `.requestCurrentPlmn()` is in a thread then the `.setText` will complain from a touching view from not ui thread exception.
- You miss a `.onError` in your .subscribe. If a request fails, the app will crash.

Comment: Hej, call 2 and 3 can be executed in parallel. I will unsubscribe the call, thanks for reminding :)

For the other two points, I forgot to change my helper methods, RxFunctions<ResponseType>applySchedulers()) is a Transformer that adds following subscribers:
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
            }
        };
    }

And the TimberErrorLoginSubscriber also covers the onError, I will change it in the question above.

Comment: @Eve but back to your original question. Use `zip` then. It's ok :)